# How to connect postgresxl with jmeter

Tags: postgres-xl

I'm trying to connect my postgresXL database with jmeter, where do i find postgresXl jdbc driver and how to connect it to jmeter?

I've tried postgreSQL jdbc driver but it does not work for me.

Comment: Postgres is not a Java application.   It is a database compiled to native executable code.   It does not run in a Java JVM.   You can not use JVM monitoring tools like Jmeter with it.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres is not a Java application. It is a database compiled to native executable code. It does not run in a Java JVM. You can not use JVM monitoring tools like Jmeter with it.